# Cross Browser Printing using iFrame in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing, cross-browser

I want to print using `iFrame` and `javascript`.
Below are my sample codes for the same:

**Javascript**

```
 function printDiv(divP) {

            window.frames["print_frame"].document.body.innerHTML = $(divP).html();
            window.frames["print_frame"].window.focus();
            window.frames["print_frame"].window.print();
        }
```

**HTML**

```
<iframe name="print_frame" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" src="about:blank">
        </iframe>
```

This Code is working in IE and Mozilla only. Other Browsers are printing White pages. I don't want to use the **Media Queries**. What could be the possible issue?

Comment: no media queries? does that rule out print style sheets?

Answer (score 1):

The solution :

Few changes :  `document.write` :( and open and close functions) + iframe 1px size..

```
 function printDiv(divP) {
  window.frames["print_frame"].document.open();
  window.frames["print_frame"].document.write('<body>aaaaaaaa</body>');
  window.frames["print_frame"].document.close();
  window.frames["print_frame"].focus();
  window.frames["print_frame"].print();
        }

printDiv()
```

http://jsbin.com/eLIQAXU/4/quiet

this is working in FF , chrome,IE ,safari :

[image]

Comment: Running this in my chrome does work.  Did you run my code ? As is ?

Comment: In your scenario "codepen..." you have to put the element <div id="printcontent" style="display:none"/> outside of <div id="allImages"  style="display:none;"> and mainly you need to add immediatlely after the body the iframe  <iframe  id='print_frame' name="print_frame" width="1" height="1" frameborder="1" src="about:blank">
        </iframe>
For me this solution  works fine: i tested on IE11 end Chrom 42

Comment: Does not work for iFrames where the src is a PDF document, unfortunately.